# How can I access a 'Browse...' dialog in Shoes?

Tags: ruby, shoes

Okay so I want to use Shoes for some of my programs, but what I absolutely need is a "Browse..." dialog so the user can browse for a directory/file locally. How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ask_open_file

ask_open_folder

Comment: I've also found that it has built-in validation.  It makes it hard to select a non-existent file.  But if you manage to, it'll throw up an error dialog and not return control back to the event handler.  At least it seemed to behave that way when I tinkered with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you target only win32-platform, you could use the Win32API-library, I guess.

Comment: Yes, that is certainly the case, however it'd be great to use easier.